# Find all vectors $X =\langle x,y,z \rangle$ for which $\langle 2,1,2\rangle \times \langle x,y,z\rangle = \langle 1,2,-2 \rangle$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, cross-product

This is a homework assignment for Calc 3 and I am kind of stuck.  Here is what i've done so far.

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    \hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\
    2 & 1 & 2 \\
    x & y & z \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
This equals:
$$[z-2y]\hat{i} - [2z-2x]\hat{j} + [2y-x]\hat{k} = <1,2,-2>$$

Then I set these equal to their components.

$$
z-2y = 1 \\
2z-2x =2 \\
2y-x = -2 \\
$$

From here I tried to solve for one of the variables.
$$
2y-x=-2 \\
+-2y+z = 1\\
$$
From this I got 
$$z=x-1$$

Plugging this into the second equation I get.
$$2(x-1)-2x=2\\
2x-2-2x=2\\
-2=2
$$

Now I know -2 does not equal 2. So I think I setup my problem wrong or I solved my system of equations wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help and sorry if I have some weird formatting errors i'm new to MathJax.

Comment: I think I just figured it out.... is my issue that my second equation should be -2z-2x =2.  Did I drop a negative?

Comment: Yes, the second equation should have been $-(2z-2x) = 2$.

Comment: @angryavian So when I do that i get the vector <0,-1,-1> which is one vector but not all of them. Should I just multiply that vector times something like t for all possible vectors?

Comment: No, there's a unique answer and you've found it.  To confirm you're right, take the cross product of the two vectors and check whether you've reached the correct result.

Comment: @RobertShore The given equation describes a line in $\mathbb R^3$, so the solution is surely not unique.

Comment: The solution set doesn’t consist of all multiples of $\langle 0,-1,-1\rangle$, as you can easily see by trying the zero vector as a solution. However, all of the solutions do lie on a line in $\mathbb R^3$, just not one that passes through the origin. Do you remember how to determine the solution set of a system of linear equations that has an infinite number of solutions?

Comment: @amd No I do not remember. I'm really struggling with this stuff in my calc class.

Comment: @amd You're right.  I just assumed the system's determinant would be non-zero but I see now that it is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I dropped a negative.  The second equation should be $−(2z−2x)=2$.

Comment: No need that I can see to delete.